# What is the UIColor of the default UITableView separator?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicolor

Can anyone tell me the UIColor name or exact RGBA for the default iPhone UITableView separator?

It looks like a light gray color, but it's not `[UIColor lightGrayColor]`; it's lighter than that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

… in terms of `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` it should be:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (
   CGContextRef c,
   224.0/255.0,
   224.0/255.0,
   224.0/255.0,
   CGFloat alpha
);
```

Quite simple and hopefully a solution for your problem.

Comment: To be more approximate, in iOS 9 it is 217.0f/255.0f for R, G & B.

Answer (score 67):

The color is not guaranteed to be a specific color. It can be changed over OS and SDK versions.
You can retrieve exact color dynamically by accessing `separatorColor` property.

```
UITableView* TV = [[UITableView alloc] init];
UIColor* C = [TV separatorColor];
CGColorRef CGC = [C CGColor];
```

Now you can get the each channel values through `UIColor`'s methods. Or use the `CGColor` directly for drawing.

Here's header file comment of the property in `UITableView.h`.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *separatorColor;
// default is the standard separator gray
```

If you want to avoid instantiation cost of `UITableView` for each time, just get it once and cache it.

---

As [@Isuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077789/isuru) noted in comment, you can write in Swift like this.

```
UITableView().separ‌​atorColor
```

As [@Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555619/jordan) noted in comment, you also can store the result to avoid further evaluation cost.

```
let defaultTableSeparato‌​rColor = UITableView().separa‌​torColor
```

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't got more upvotes, perfect solution imo :)

Comment: @Jason because it's expensive if you just need a color.

Comment: @Andy This is (or maybe, and hopefully was) the only way to get semantically correct color. Others are all semantically wrong. Though most people just can satisfy with approximated result, but still it doesn't mean that's correct.

Comment: @Eonil too bad separatorColor is not UIAppearance compliant, otherwise it might be easier to get. I agree with you regarding approximation, but you might not even notice any difference on screen. In a long shot your solution is next OS ready if Apple changed a color scheme.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I agree that color change is unlikely to happen, and the app would be updated before the SDK changes.

Comment: This is neat. In iOS 8 with Swift, you can just get this in one line without instantiating. `UITableView().seperatorColor`.

Comment: @Isuru when you call UITableView() you are instantiating a UITableView

Comment: To add to the swift answer... since global properties are lazily computed, at the top of the file you need to use it, just use a one line, auto cached value: `private let defaultTableSeparatorColor = UITableView().separatorColor`

Answer (score 26):

It seems it changed for **iOS 7**:

Now the colour is RGB(200, 199, 204):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0 green:199/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

And don't forget the proper line height is 1 px. The code for creating corresponding UIView:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 1/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale])];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0 green:199/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 3**

Just set to nil to revert to default.

```
tableView.separatorColor = nil
```

Comment: Best answer here!

Answer (score 18):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:224/255.0 green:224/255.0 blue:224/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3.0.1, you can do something like this

```
yourView.backgroundColor = UITableView().separ‌​atorColor
```

Answer (score 6):

R: 224 G: 224 B: 224

I hope that helps!

Comment: What is that in terms of `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` (floats)?

Answer (score 6):

To find out any colours on your iOS device, just run the app in the Simulator then use Apple's DigitalColor Meter (in your utilities folder) and hover over the colour you need info on. Alternatively just do a screen grab from the phone, open that in Preview and use DigitalColor Meter to read the colour values.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW:

`UIColor *defaultSeparatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.783922f green:0.783922f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f];`

This was found simulating **iOS 9.0** -- and logging out the floating point values that a UITableView separatorColor has by default.  I do not find that this matches any of the values from the other answers, but rather exacts the result of the code in the other answer here where the separatorColor is set via creation of a UITableView *tempTable.

Answer (score 2):

Guys it's very simple:

```
UITableView().separatorColor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView * tempTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];

[table setSeparatorColor:tempTable.separatorColor];
[table setSeparatorStyle:tempTable.separatorStyle];
table.backgroundView = tempTable.backgroundView;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Screenshot -> Photoshop -> Pick Color Tool -> RGB(227, 227, 229)`

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15.5, Separator Color Value is:

```
let separatorColor = UIColor.separator
// R:0.24, G:0.24, B:0.26, A:0.29
```

By the way, you can get this value by "Debug View Hierarchy" in Xcode.