# How to tune this UITableView so that I can get what I want?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to fit a static UITableView into a UIViewController
The problem I am facing right now as you can see from the image is that

[image]

This is a UITableView in a "Plain" mode (instead of "Grouped")
You can see the bottom line (where the table ends) shows correctly. But there is no line at the top (where the table begins).

Is there any way that I can add one line there either programatically or via xcode, other than just drag in a UIView which has a grey background with 1 point for the height?

Thanks

Comment: In order to use static cells, I thought you had to drag UITableViewController from the objects library onto the canvas.

Comment: I agree with you but I have some other constrains that doesn't allow me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a 1 pixel wide header

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)]; //It will stretch
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: If anyone is looking for the exact colour that fits other separator, you can refer to this [What is the UIColor of the default UITableView separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446279/what-is-the-uicolor-of-the-default-uitableview-separator)